# Use of __clone in PHP?

Tags: php, object

I have a class a and instantiated it using new

```
$obja = new a;
```

I know the difference between the below two lines

```
$obja2 = $ojba;
$obja2 = clone $obja;
```

But even if you declare or not declare __clone in the class a the first line $obja2 refer to $obja memory space and second line creates a copy of the $obja. Till here it is clear to me.

Then why php is having a magic method __clone?
Is it only for executing a set of codes which is written inside __clone while we use $obja2 = clone $obja;

Somebody please help to get a better idea of it.

Comment: It exists to allow you to clone any object instances held within the object if you need to - by default the pointers would be copied but the new object would effectively have the same instances of the child objects.

Comment: @DaveRandom : Can u explain a bit more simpler :) may be a link or anything that better explains this. i have already done my googling

Comment: Consider an object of class `A` with a property `$innerB`, which contains an instance of the class `B`. When you clone the instance of `A`, the new object will have the same instance of `B`. By using clone, you could do `$this->innerB = clone $this->innerB;` - so you get a new instance of `B` for the new object as well. Consider [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ngssxa) vs [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/51YWiC).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> ```
> void __clone ( void )
> ```
>
> Once the cloning is complete, if a `__clone()` method is defined, then
>   the newly created object's `__clone()` method will be called, to allow
>   any necessary properties that need to be changed.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone

So yes, it's a *callback* after the `clone` operation has finished. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: so what is the problems that it creates if i don't write __clone() in a class?

Comment: That depends on what you want/need to do. Is the default behavior of a PHP `clone` operation sufficient for what you want to do when cloning objects? Then there's no need. If you need to do more things to make a "complete" clone, add that code in the `__clone` callback method. Lame example: if each of your objects needs to have a unique ID (`$this->id` variable or something along those lines), you'll need to generate a new ID after a clone to avoid having two objects with the same ID.

Comment: Other example: `clone` creates a "shallow copy". This means, that only the object itself gets cloned, but not its associations. So if this object of `A` has associations to other objects, which _must_ be unique between difference instances `A`, you must clone the associations within `__clone()` too: `$this->otherObject = clone $this->otherObject;`

Comment: Note that **ONLY `__clone`** called during `clone(A)` is the **`A::__clone()`** - if `A` has an inner property `B $b`, *`B::__clone()` **will not be called** even though implemented!*

Answer (score 25):

The `clone` keyword in PHP represents a **shallow copy**.

In order to achieve a **deep copy**, you need to implement the magic method `__clone`

If you clone an object that has a member which is an object of another class with the simple `clone` keyword, you would be keeping the same reference to that second object.

That's where the **deep copy** comes in handy, with something like this:

```
public function __clone()
{
    $this->someOtherObject = clone $this->someOtherObject;
}
```

With that, you guarantee the clone will be **deep**, meaning it will clone the member objects as well, instead of just keeping the original reference to them.

Comment: I would like to note, that this **does *NOT* guarantee the clone to be deep** if the referenced object has also referenced objects - you may think *"oh I have only a data class"* - but ***think again***, maybe it has a DateTime or some sort of Collection property or something.